# OnQueryHitPoint

Tags: visual-c++

I have ActiveX control developed using VC++. When user clicks on my control, i dont want to handle it and want to pass it to controls below it. (This will be useful if my control is on top of other controls)

To achieve it, i have implemented OnQueryHitPoint() on my control. This works fine when my control is used in VB. But OnQueryHitPoint() is NOT called at all when my control used in VC++.

I appreciate any ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. I need to override OnNcHitTest() and return HTTRANSPARENT. Hope it will help someone.

Thanks.